# Konjunktiv 2 zum Ausdrücken reiner Fakten

Tags: grammar, subjunctive

In einer Diskussion darüber, was der Konjunktiv 2 alles ausdrücken kann oder auch nicht, verwendete ich folgendes Beispiel:

> Ich hätte die Möglichkeit ein Praktikum zu machen. Ist aber unbezahlt. Was meint ihr … soll ich oder nicht?

Ein solcher Satz findet sich in der Art in zahlreichen Foren. Mir ging es bei dem Beispiel primär darum, zu zeigen, dass K2 auch 100 % reale Fakten ausdrücken kann … die Person HAT die Möglichkeit, daran besteht kein Zweifel.

Mein Diskussionspartner, den ich bat, dieses Beispiel einer der Standardfunktionen des K2 zuzuordnen, meinte, je länger er über das Beispiel nachdächte, desto weniger würde er glauben, dass es richtig ist. Darum nun diese Frage.

- Ist ein solcher Satz grammatisch korrekt? (Ich sage klar „ja“, dazu wird er oft genug verwendet, aber man weiß ja nie, was Standardgrammatiken oder der Zwiebelfisch so schreiben.)... *diese Frage ist blöd gestellt. Lasse sie drin, da schon AW existieren. Bitte nicht mehr drauf eingehen. SIEHE EDIT*
- Um welche Art K2 handelt es sich (Irrealis, Höflichkeitalis, Wunschalis etc.)
- Gibt es einen Bedeutungsunterschied zum reinen Indikativ?
- Wenn nein, was genau macht der K2 hier?

EDIT:

- Sind solche Formulierungen Standarddeutsch, oder werden sie in der Germanistik/Linguistik als umgangsprachlich angesehen, da der K2 hier eigentlich nicht hingehört? (bitte nur mit Quellen antworten, keine persönliche Meinung)

Comment: Als Denkfutter für potentielle Antwortende: Während ich es schwierig finde, zu entscheiden, ob der Beispielsatz in der Frage richtig ist, würde ich im folgenden Beispiel den Konjunktiv garantiert als falsch einstufen: »Er hat die Möglichkeit, ein Praktikum zu machen. Ich weiß aber nicht, ob er das Angebot schon angenommen hat.«

Comment: Die 4. Auflage der Duden-Grammatik (1984) behandelt dies unter den irrealen Aussage- und Fragesätzen und spricht von der Verwendung in _einer vorsichtigen, unaufdringlich-zurückhaltenden Feststellung_; sie weist darauf hin, daß der Indikativ _in diesen Fällen härter und schroffer wirken_ würde.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: _Er hätte die Möglichkeit._ Gar kein Problem für mich.

Comment: Den Zwiebelfisch würde ich einfach ignorieren. Sein romanistischer Hintergrund macht ihn nicht zu einem Linguisten. Meistens stimmts trotzdem, aber ich hab auch immer wieder Dinge bei ihm gelesen, die schlicht beweisbar falsch waren.

Comment: Meines Erachtens handelt es sich um schlechtes Deutsch. "Ich hätte die Möglichkeit ein Praktikum zu machen, wenn ..."  (z.B. "wenn ich in Deutschland bliebe"). Ich meine, dass das "wenn" hier zwingend ist, bzw. dass man "Ich habe die Möglichkeit ein Praktikum zu machen" sagt, wobei "die Möglichkeit" den Konjunktiv hinreichend ausdrückt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ich halte es für einen Potentialis.
Der Indikativ hat den „Nachteil“, auch für allgemeingültige Aussagen genommen zu werden, die keinen Bezug zur aktuellen Situation haben. Ein Vergleich:

> (1) Wenn ich aus dem Haus gehe, kann mich ein Hund beißen.
>   (2) Wenn ich aus dem Haus gehe, könnte mich ein Hund beißen.

Satz (2) stellt eindeutig einen Satz zur aktuellen Situation her: Ich habe *jetzt* Angst, dass mich ein Hund beißt, wenn ich *jetzt* aus dem Haus gehe. (1) gilt hingegen immer und ist daher geeignet für allgemeingültige Aussagen ohne Bezug zur konkreten Situation.

Für das Praktikum gilt, dass der Sprecher von einem *konkreten* Praktikum spricht, und dass er sich akut mit der Frage auseinandersetzt, ob er es macht oder nicht (und deshalb die Frage stellt). Dies ist dem Sprecher in der Situation besonders wichtig; die reine Faktenlage – dass er überhaupt die Möglichkeit hat – ist unwichtig.

Es ist generell ein schwieriges Thema, da der Konjunktiv hier nicht einer „harten“ grammatischen Regel folgt, sondern primär die Sprecherintention entscheidend ist, die aber nicht speziell markiert werden kann. Für Muttersprachler ist das kein Problem, das in eine Regel zu formulieren hingegen schon.

Edith: 
Ich kann keine Quellen anbieten, aber der Duden akzeptiert beispielsweise das doppelte Präteritumperfekt, weil es Goethe mindestens einmal verwendet hat (das doppelte Präsensperfekt bleibt hingegen „Dialekt“). Also habe ich mal bei Goethe gesucht:

> doch in einem Nu schnappten die Wasser ab, und ich stand nun feucht auf einem durchnäßten Boden. die Gegenwart des alten Mannes, der unvermutet vor mich trat, war mir keineswegs willkommen; ich *hätte* gewünscht, mich, wo nicht verbergen, doch wenigstens verhüllen zu können (Dichtung und Wahrheit)

Ebenso möglich und eigentlich gemeint:

> Ich habe mir gewünscht, mich, wo nicht verbergen, doch wenigstens verhüllen zu können.

Anderes Beispiel (Dichtung und Wahrheit):

> der alte messianische Freund trat endlich herein, die Tränen standen ihm in den Augen; er faßte mich beim Arm und sagte: "es tut mir herzlich leid, daß ich in solcher Angelegenheit zu Ihnen komme. ich *hätte* nicht gedacht, daß Sie sich so weit verirren könnten.

Tatsächlich:

> Ich habe nicht gedacht, dass sie sich so weit verirren könnten.

Ich kann mich auch nicht daran erinnern, dass jemand in der Schule oder anderswo deswegen verbessert oder getadelt worden wäre. Eine erschöpfende Untersuchung des Konjunktivs, die zu einer systematischen Darstellung der Verwendung führt, täte mal not. Tut not.

Ein weiterer Hinweis – Deutsch ist die Sprache der Modalität, der Kunst, etwas zu sagen, ohne es zu sagen. Im vorletzten Satz des letzten Absatzes vermeide ich, die Untersuchung direkt zu fordern – ich schwäche die Forderung mit dem Konjunktiv und der Modalpartikel ab. Hui, ist der Brei heiß, da sollte ich ja mal doch noch etwas drum herumschleichen.

Comment: Ich kann Dir leider nicht folgen: Weil der Sprecher über Fakten sprechen möchte, nutzt er einen Potentialis, welcher wiederum ein Konjunktiv 2 ist? Außerdem führt der [Konjunktiv als Potentialis](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potentialis) im Deutschen ein ziemliches Nieschendasein und wird von einigen ganz bestritten.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft: (1) ist eine Aussage, die solange richtig ist, solange es Hunde gibt; ich empfinde sie jedoch als relativ unnütz, da evident. In (2) wird deutlich, dass der Sprecher konkrete Angst davor hat, dass ihn ein Hund beißen wird. Bei dem Praktikum geht es eben darum, dass die Frage, ob er es machen wird oder nich, akut im Raum steht.

Comment: +1 für den Bedeutungsunterschied. Kann ich gut nachvollziehen/fühlt sich für mich auch so an. Was mir noch ein bisschen fehlt, ist, was in der Literatur zu dieser Verwendung so gesagt wird. Ich hatte nach "Grammatik" gefragt. Das war unglücklich formuliert. Ich meinte eher, ob es als "umgangssprachlich" angesehen wird, aber eigentlich ohne K2 würde stehen müssen.

Answer (score 1):

Das erinnert mich an das wienerische »Es warad wegen ...« (hochdeutsch: »Es wäre wegen ...«)

[image]

Auch hier wird der Konjunktiv *wäre* verwendet, wo eigentlich der Indikativ (in diesem Fall »*ist*« angebracht wäre.

Ähnliches Beispiel, das ich von meiner Frau manchmal höre, wenn wir fortgehen wollen, und sie nach kurzer Wartezeit endlich fertig frisiert aus dem Bad kommt:

> I warad jetzt fertig. (Ich wäre jetzt fertig.)

In beiden Beispielen wird ebenfalls eine Tatsache durch den Konjunktiv II ausgedrückt.

Zu den gestellten Fragen:

1. **Ist ein solcher Satz grammatisch korrekt?**
   Eindeutig ja. Der Konjunktiv II wurde in allen Beispielen regelkonform gebildet. (Ob der K2 semantisch korrekt ist, wurde nicht gefragt, und hat mit der Grammatik wenig zu tun. Siehe auch Frage 3.)
2. **Um welche Art K2 handelt es sich?**
   Bei dem Spruch auf dem Wahlplakat handelt es sich um einen Höflichkeits-Konjunktiv, und zwar um jene Variante, bei der der Sprecher Bescheidenheit ausdrücken will. Auch »*Ich wäre jetzt fertig*« passt in diese Kategorie.
   Aber bei »*Ich hätte die Möglichkeit*« trifft das nicht zu, weil einerseits der Sprecher keine Bescheidenheit ausdrücken will, und weil andererseits ja ausdrücklich von einer *Möglichkeit* die Rede ist. Mit diesen Satz wird also eine Vermutung ausgedrückt, denn es steht noch nicht mit Sicherheit fest, dass das Praktikum tatsächlich besucht werden wird. Insofern ist hier die Funktion des Konjunktiv, die semantische Aussage zu verstärken.
3. **Gibt es einen Bedeutungsunterschied zum reinen Indikativ?**
   »*Ich **habe** die Möglichkeit etwas zu tun*« ist zwar grammatisch ein Indikativ, semantisch (inhaltlich) ist hier aber nach wie vor von einer Möglichkeit, also einer unklaren Situation die Rede.
   In »*Ich **hätte** die Möglichkeit*« wird nun mit der Grammatik ebenfalls das ausgedrückt, was in der wörtlichen Bedeutung der Aussage steckt. Die Tatsache, dass der Besuch des Praktikums nur um eine Möglichkeit (also keinesfalls beschlossene Sache) ist, kommt nun auch auf einer zweiten sprachlichen Ebene zum Ausdruck. Hier wirkt also die Grammatik als Verstärkung der Semantik.
4. **Wenn nein, was genau macht der K2 hier?**
   Die Prämisse (*wenn nein*) trifft nicht zu.